# Jenkins job status control how to change it?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jobs, status

I'm using RTC plugin to checkout source code and for some unbeknownst reason, while functionally working fine, it spits out a null pointer (I don't know how to debug it further), which looks like this:

```
 13:26:28 RTC Checkout : Fetching files to fetch destination "C:\.jenkins\jobs\...
 13:26:49 RTC Checkout : Fetching Completed
 13:26:49 ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Nothing else about it is printed in the log. Now this the build runs fine, all other tasks/steps execute and complete, but even if they all pass, the build still gets marked as Finished: FAILURE

I believe (I am sure?) it's because of this strange nullpointer in SCM plugin of Jenkins. Is there any way to tell Jenkins to ignore this step or mark build successful based on other criteria (example maven BUILD SUCCESS output)? It's probably too difficult to fix the RTC plugin, so I want to tell Jenkins how to set the Finish status correctly...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the jdk I was using on the build server. I turned off every part of the job that could be turned on/off and eventually tracked it down to this... I was using jdk8 installed via Jenkins, which I guess is automatically downloaded from Oracle by Jenkins itself? Anyway, I installed jdk 8 locally on the build server, pointed Jenkins to that installation instead of the jenkins managed one and violla, everything worked. The fact that the exception was thrown after SCM plugin finished was just misleading. Looks like a bug.